# Terraform cannot create Azure recovery service vault in Canada East and US West?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-site-recovery

I have written some terraform code for the recovery service vault. It does not create the vault in Canada East and US West.

It gives the following error code:

```
azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: creating Vault (Subscription: "****"
│ Resource Group Name: "mydev-rg"
│ Vault Name: "mydev-vault"): backupresourcestorageconfigsnoncrr.BackupResourceStorageConfigsNonCRRClient#Update: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="UserErrorInvalidRequestParameter" Message="Parameter NO_PARAM in request is invalid. Please provide correct value for parameter NO_PARAM"
│ 
│   with azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup_vault,
│   on main.tf line 22, in resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup_vault":
│   22: resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup_vault" {
│ 
╵
```

Below is my full terraform code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.40.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "backup_vault" {
  name     = "mydev-rg"
  location = var.rg_location

}

# Create Azure Site Recovery Vault
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup_vault" {
  name                = "mydev-vault"
  location            = var.rg_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.backup_vault.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  soft_delete_enabled = true

  public_network_access_enabled = false
  storage_mode_type             = "ZoneRedundant"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.backup_vault
  ]
}

#variables
variable "subscription_id" {
  type = string
}
variable "rg_location" {
  type = string
}
```

I managed to create the vault in different regions by equating var.rg_location with (eg. eastus, uksouth) except canadaeast and westus.

Comment: Could you please add your complete main.tf code, also passed inputs and the complete error message when you run terraform apply and it got failed.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda Added full terraform code.

Answer (score 0):

*I also got the same error when I tried in my environment previously.*

[image]

The issue occurs with the `storage_mode_type = "ZoneRedundant"` setting. As explained in this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/279033/recovery-service-vault-in-canada), you need to select it from the list of availability zones. And it is not supported for the recovery services vault. You can instead give it as a `geo redundant`. Geo redundancy functions similarly by protecting the site/vault from disasters and outages that affect a specific region.

***I modified your code as below and was able to create the recovery services vault in Canada East as follows:***

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.54.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "backup_vault" {
  name     = "mydev-rg"
  location = "CanadaEast"

}
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "vault" {
  name                = "mydev-vault"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.backup_vault.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.backup_vault.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  soft_delete_enabled = true
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.backup_vault
  ]
}
```

*Executed* `terraform init` & validated the configuration with `terraform validate`:

[image]

*Executed* `terraform plan`:

[image]

*Executed* `terraform apply`:

[image]

*Successfully deployed in Canada East region as shown:*

[image]

Comment: thanks I got it! I use LocallyRedundant and is able to deploy too.